# Getting Plugin directory and url

Tags: plugin-development

In one of my theme the path and directory is set by

```
if( !defined('ADMIN_PATH') )
define( 'ADMIN_PATH', get_template_directory() . '/admin/' );
if( !defined('ADMIN_DIR') )
define( 'ADMIN_DIR', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/' );
```

If I want to convert it into plugin what will be the correct way?I have tried  plugins_url(), plugin_dir_url() but those didn't work.

Comment: Convert what into a plugin? Is the path changing? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want  ADMIN_PATH and ADMIN_DIR relative to plugin not to theme.Replace get_template_directory() with  plugins_url()..like this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) and [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) helper functions:

```
if( ! defined( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH' ) )
    define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __file__ ) . 'admin/' );
if( ! defined( 'MY_PLUGIN_DIR' ) )
    define( 'MY_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_url( __file__ ) . 'admin/' );
```

You should be using more unique constant names - `ADMIN_PATH` is far too generic.